# Why the exported result is different from the evaluated result

Tags: plotting

[image]

Why the exported result is different from the evaluated result?
How to set to make them the same!

Here's the code, It needs the package MaTeX. It's Ok, If you don't use this package, just make sure the text remain the same size when evaluating and exporting.

`````
\[Gamma] = 7/18 \[Pi];
a1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], LightBlue, Sphere[], Opacity[1], Black,
     Thick, Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
    Line[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}];
a2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
a3 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
a4 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
data = Table[{0, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 3 \[Pi]/2, 5 \[Pi]/4, -0.01}];
a5 = Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[0.035], Arrow[Tube[data, 0.01]]}];
data = Table[{0, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, \[Pi], 1.5 \[Pi]/2, -0.01}];
a6 = Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[0.035], Arrow[Tube[data, 0.01]]}];
data = Table[{0, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, \[Pi]/2, 3 \[Pi]/2, 0.01}];
a7 = Graphics3D[{Green, Tube[data, 0.01]}];
a8 = Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{0, -1, 0}, 0.05]}];
a9 = Show[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0], 
   ViewPoint -> {\[Pi], -1.4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/1.5}];
data = Table[{-Cos[t] Sin[\[Gamma]], Cos[t] Cos[\[Gamma]], 
    Sin[t]}, {t, (1.5 \[Pi])/2, (1.75 \[Pi])/2, 0.01}];
b1 = Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[0.035], Arrow[Tube[data, 0.01]]}];
data = Table[{-Cos[t] Sin[\[Gamma]], Cos[t] Cos[\[Gamma]], 
   Sin[t]}, {t, (2 \[Pi])/2, (2.25 \[Pi])/2, 0.01}]; b2 = 
 Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[0.035], 
   Arrow[Tube[data, 0.01]]}]; data = 
 Table[{-Cos[t] Sin[\[Gamma]], Cos[t] Cos[\[Gamma]], 
   Sin[t]}, {t, \[Pi]/2, (3 \[Pi])/2, 0.01}]; b3 = 
 Graphics3D[{Green, Tube[data, 0.01]}];
data = Table[{0.2 Sin[t], -0.2 Cos[t], 0}, {t, 0, \[Gamma], 
   0.01}]; b4 = 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[Tube[data, 0.008]]}]; b5 = 
 Graphics3D[{Red, 
   Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sin[\[Gamma]], -Cos[\[Gamma]], 0}}, 0.008]}];
b6 = Rasterize[
  Show[{a9, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}], 
  RasterSize -> 3000]

c1 = Graphics[
   Text[MaTeX[
     TeXForm[StringTemplate["\[Gamma] = ``\[Degree]"][
       Floor[\[Gamma] 180/\[Pi]]]], FontSize -> 30], {0, -0.1}]];
c2 = Canvas[c1, FrameStyle -> False, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Background -> b6, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]
Export["带闭合路径的庞加莱球   " <> 
   DateString[{"(Date ", "ISODate", " Time ", "Hour", "-", "Minute", 
     "-", "Second", ")"}] <> ".pdf", c2] // SystemOpen
````
`````

Comment: Export has options.  Can you give an example we can discuss on?

Comment: Welcome Lawrence. Can you, please, provide for those wishing to help you the appropriate code to replicate such issues? Or, at the very least, provide code for a minimum working example (MWE)? Thanks!